# Extending the Django User Model OneToOne - User profile not saving

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build an application that allows users to register and meet other users with similar interests. I am extending the user model using a OneToOne field but I run into a problem when I try to register some users: **The profile does not save.** The user data saves, but the profile data does not.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong, as I followed a tutorial to write the program.

This is my **Models.py** file:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    GENDERS = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDERS, max_length=1, null=True, default='')
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    hobby = models.ManyToManyField(Hobby)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

This is my **forms.py** file:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name')

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('email', 'gender', 'dob', 'hobby')
```

This is my view function:

```
def register(request):
if request.method =="POST":
    userForm = UserForm(request.POST)
    profileForm = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    if userForm.is_valid() and profileForm.is_valid():
        userForm.save()
        profileForm.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'QMLove/register.html', {'userForm': userForm, 'profileForm': profileForm})
else:
    userForm = UserForm()
    profileForm = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'QMLove/register.html',{'userForm': userForm, 'profileForm': profileForm})
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Am I correct that Profile record is created but with no data?

Comment: @IvanStarostin, yes. My silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't done anything to associate the Profile you're creating with the User you've created. I would expect either two profiles two be created - one empty and one with data but not associated with the user - or for the profile form save to fail with an integrityerror because you didn't supply the user.

You should remove those signal receivers because they won't help with what you want to do and will probably create conflicts. Instead, pass the created user when you save the profile:

```
user = userForm.save()
profile = profileForm.save(commit=False)
profile.user = user
profile.save()
```

Comment: Hello Daniel, that was spot on. As soon as I removed the signal receivers and I made the corrections you suggested, the application worked. 

I have accepted your answer. Thank you, once again!